# Display Javascript Ajax webservice request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was trying to display an ajax request from a web service in my HTML.
I can display the result in the console but can not retrieve the result and then display it in my HTML.
I want to display the result of the request in "weather-result" div by clicking the "ask-weather" button.
Her is my code.
Thank everyone.

```js
const askWeather = function(result){
  
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function subFunction() {
      if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
          result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          return result.current_condition.condition;
      }
  };
    request.open("GET", "https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris");
  request.send();
  
}

const ask = document.getElementById('ask-weather');
ask.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const weatherResult = document.getElementById('weather-result');
  weatherResult.innerHTML = askWeather();
  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div><button id="ask-weather">Quelle est la météo sur Paris ?</button></div>
    <div id="weather-result"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there a reason to do `weatherResult.innerHTML = askWeather()`? Things might work better if instead of returning the result of the XMLHttpRequest, you just make the change to the innerHTML _inside_ the handler (`subFunction`). You know, asynchronous instead of synchronous.

Comment: its 2020 the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API is much cleaner and widely supported `fetch("https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris").then(res => res.json()).then(data => document.getElementById('ask-weather').innerHTML = data.current_condition.condition)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a asynchronous/callback problem here. When the button is clicked, it sends a request somewhere and will return right away (with `undefined` in case of the code above - this can be checked by saving it in a variable and `console.log` it).

When `askWeather()` is called, it could return something itself. The `return` in `request.onreadystatechange` cannot return for `askWeather` as it's happening multiple times and later - after `askWeather` is done and the request is being sent.

If you pass a function a variable and set it to something new in its body, it will not be changed for the caller. That means doing `result = ...` does not really help, if you wanted to pass a variabel and get it set by the inner function.

A different approach is necessary to handle this. Here are a few alternatives:

1. To keep it as most similar to the code you had, you can set the `innerHTML` in the `onreadystatechange` function:

```
const askWeather = function() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function subFunction() {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
      const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // set it here directly
      const weatherResult = document.getElementById('weather-result');
      weatherResult.innerHTML = result.current_condition.condition;
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", "https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris");
  request.send();
}

const ask = document.getElementById('ask-weather');
ask.addEventListener('click', function() {
  askWeather();
});
```

2. Make it more general and let `askWeather` use a callback (call a function when it's "done"):

```
const askWeather = function(callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function subFunction() {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
      const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // send the result to the passed "callback" function
      callback(result.current_condition.condition);
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", "https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris");
  request.send();
}

const ask = document.getElementById('ask-weather');
ask.addEventListener('click', function() {
  askWeather(function (result) { // this whole function is the "callback" parameter
    const weatherResult = document.getElementById('weather-result');
    weatherResult.innerHTML = result;
  });
});
```

3. (a) Let `askWeather` return a promise and use it in the caller

```
const askWeather = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function subFunction() {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
      const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // send the result to the passed "callback" function
      resolve(result.current_condition.condition);
    }
    // not sure about the error path here, but something like this:
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status != 200) {
      reject(new Error("There was an error with the XMLHttpRequest!"));
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", "https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris");
  request.send();
});

const ask = document.getElementById('ask-weather');
ask.addEventListener('click', function() {
  askWeather()
    .catch((err) => weatherResult.innerHTML = err.message) // to handle possible errors, maybe?
    .then((result) => { // like the callback solution, but as promise!
      const weatherResult = document.getElementById('weather-result');
      weatherResult.innerHTML = result;
    });
  });
});
```

3. (b) Additionally to the Promise solution, in newer browsers there is already `async` and `await` syntax:

```
ask.addEventListener('click', async function() {
  try {
    const result = await askWeather(); // this "pauses" until the Promise return of `askWeather` resolves (or throws an error if it doesn't)
    const weatherResult = document.getElementById('weather-result');
    weatherResult.innerHTML = result;
  } catch (e) {
    // error could be handled here
  }
});
```

4. Instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, use the `fetch` API, which usually should be available if Promises are available in the browsers you support. The solution is in the comments of the original question. With most modern browsers, this should work:

```
ask.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris");
  const result = await response.json();
  const weatherResult = document.getElementById('ask-weather');
  weatherResult.innerHTML = result.current_condition.condition;
});
```

If you don't have to support IE, I would use the fetch alternative.

I hope the other alternatives make it clear, asynchronous patterns can be resolved in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getJSON(path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('GET', path, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if ((this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) || this.status === 304) {
          var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

          resolve(response);
        } else {
          var error = this.statusText;

          reject('Http/App Error: ' + error);
        }
      }
    }
    xhttp.onerror = processError;
    xhttp.onabort = processError;
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp = null;

    function processError(err) {
      reject('Network Error: ' + err.target.status);
    }
  });
}

const ask = document.getElementById('ask-weather')
const weather = document.getElementById('weather-result')
const endpoint = 'https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/paris'

ask.addEventListener('click', function() {
  getJSON(endpoint).then((success) => {
    const response = success.current_condition.condition

    weather.innerHTML = response
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

This is a simple example using Promise. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyv3e47u/) working.